# Python-Social-Auth fails with mongoEngine (Django)

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, django-socialauth

I try to make `python-social-auth` work with `mongodb`.

I follow the instructions [here](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/django.html) that say to add:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'social.apps.django_app.me',
    ...
)
```

and

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social.apps.django_app.me.models.DjangoStorage'
```

However something goes wrong and I get an ImportError:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x101c51d50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/me/models.py", line 29, in <module>
    'mongoengine.django.auth.User'
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py", line 21, in module_member
    module = import_module(mod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py", line 15, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named auth
```

Also in my settings.py I have the following code. If I comment out the `'social.apps.django_app.me',` I will not have a database connected with the social-auth. If I leave it, the code fails.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',

    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'social.apps.django_app.me', # this is the line that fails
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
)



# Engine stuff
SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

#AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'

MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'


_MONGODB_USER = '***'      #real stuf here
_MONGODB_PASSWD = '***'    #real stuf here
_MONGODB_HOST = '***'      #real stuf here
_MONGODB_NAME = '****'     #real stuf here
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
    'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' \
    % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)

mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)

# Auth Stuff
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social.apps.django_app.me.models.DjangoStorage'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '***'        #real stuf here
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '***'     #real stuf here
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email','user_location']
```

Do I miss something to add? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was trying this my self and seems that the default value for `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is causing errors, the default value is `auth.User` which refs to `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. But defining it to `mongoengine.django.auth.User` makes django complain about the format not being `app_name.ModelName`.

Defining `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

MongoEngine provides two distinct methods to provide authentication in django:

- [Classic Authentication](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html#authentication) supports as far as Django 1.3,
- Using the [Custom User Model](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html#custom-user-model) introduced in Django 1.5.

Only the first one will work with python-social-auth (as of v0.1.17).

### Classic Authentication

Basically, you just need to use a custom authentication backend:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
```

You shouldn't set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, as this is used to define a Custom User Model. Here, Django's models are just ignored.

The user document class used to store users is defined by `MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT`, which defaults to `'mongoengine.django.auth.User'`. You can update this value if you want to write your custom user class.

Then, it's just a matter of setting the same user document class for Social-Auth, as omab pointed:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'
```

This is the option python-social-auth supports.

### Custom User Model

Django 1.5 introduced a new way to define a custom user model class, which this method makes use of. Authentication will be done using the standard Django authentication backend:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

`AUTH_USER_MODEL` must be set to `'mongo_auth.MongoUser'`, which does point to `mongoengine.django.mongo_auth.MongoUser` (using Django's `app_name.model_name` notation).

This `MongoUser` model is not directly used (as it's a Django Model), it's just a way to tell Django to use another model using Django's [Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). The manager on this model will simply return MongoEngine documents defined by `MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT` as above.

Unfortunately, this method is not supported by python-social-auth, as it expects `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to be a MongoEngine document, while it is actually a proxy Django Model.

I created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/pull/134) to try and fix the issue.