# MongoEngine -- how to custom User model / custom backend for authenticate()

Tags: django, authentication, mongoengine, custom-backend

**SUMMARY**

**How do I use a custom User model *and* a custom authentication backend (to allow for email / password authentication) with Django + MongoEngine?**  (Is a custom backend even necessary for that? ...i.e., to use an email for username when authenticating with MongoEngine.)

**Is there any documentation with a straight-forward (and complete!) example of using a *custom user object* while using *Mongo* as the primary datastore when *authenticating* in Django?** (Postgres has such clearer and more comprehensive docs...)

**DETAIL**

MongoEngine seems to give you just two flavors of authentication--the "Classic" (aka '*mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend*') way...OR...the "Custom User Model" (aka '*django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend*') way--both of which more or less succinctly outlined in Nicolas Cortot's answer to a different question here:
[Python-Social-Auth fails with mongoEngine (Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947938/python-social-auth-fails-with-mongoengine-django)

Both of these authentication techniques give you access to an *authenticate()* method similar to Django's AbstractBaseUser class--a method which relies on a *check_password* function. However, the minute you use the so-called "Custom User Model" flavor of authentication (as outlined in the above link)...*and* then pair that with a custom backend (in order to use emails for usernames)...you run into trouble due to the absence of access to the typical authenticate() function.

For example, like so...

#### accounts.models.py

```
# ...with postgres, I'd subclass AbstractBaseUser...but with Mongo...(?)

from django.conf import settings
from mongoengine.fields import EmailField, BooleanField 

from mongoengine.django.auth import User

class MyUser(User):

    email = EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_active = BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ''

    ...
```

#### my_custom_backend.py

```
# ...is a custom backend even necessary to use email for authentication instead of username?

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password
#from mongoengine.django.auth import check_password
#from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from models import MyUser

    class EmailAuthBackend(object):

        def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):

# ...uh oh, since I'm NOT using one of the usual backends with a pre-existing authenticate()
# method, there ain't a native check_password() function available. Means I have to hash the
# password, etc.
```

So, *seemingly*, I'm obliged to write my own check_password function. To get all of the  goodness inherent with the *AbstractBaseUser* class typically found with a PostgreSQL authentication, I'd have to totally inflate my custom User model, which seems hacky and can't be very DRY.

Am I getting totally confused here? ...i.e., is it actually totally unnecessary to use a custom backend if I want to use emails instead of usernames for authentication when using MongoEngine?

I feel like I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Django works with MongoEngine in regard to authentication, and with regard to how I've modeled and called upon custom user object / my particular subclassing of MongoEngine's user object during that process...

Because--as it is right now--I'm getting an "**'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'**" error message in the browser. I also noted that this problem sometimes exists for unexpected reasons--namely: perhaps, the authenticate() method expects a hashed password, or because the login (email) is too long...? For more instances where this latter circumstance might be the case, see:

[Django Register Form 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770848/django-register-form-anonymoususer-object-has-no-attribute-backend)

#### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',
    'accounts',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
    #'accounts.my_custom_backend.EmailAuthBackend',
    #'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'
MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'accounts.models.User'
```

#### accounts.views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login
from my_custom_backend import EmailAuthBackend
from forms import AuthenticationForm

def login(request):

    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            backend = EmailAuthBackend()
            user = backend.authenticate(email=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password'])
            django_login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        except DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse('user does not exist')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render_to_response('accounts/login.html',
       { 'form': form },
       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, looks like the best course of action isn't to hand over Django's User to Mongo for authentication to begin with... Got this golden nugget via Twitter:

[@blogblimp](https://twitter.com/blogblimp) my short answer: try to avoid replacing Django user models with MongoDB. You lose all the Django power and lose MongoDB's speed. 
Seriously, user relates to everything and MongoDB isn't relational.

— Daniel Roy Greenfeld (@pydanny) [January 20, 2014](https://twitter.com/pydanny/statuses/425103632032215041)

So: I'll just leverage PostgreSQL for authentication, and Mongo for other objects. That means naming / connecting to two databases in the Django settings. In retrospect, I guess the moral is: never use Mongo just because it's cool. Mongo is still a second-class citizen in the Django world.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm a little late, but I could achieve the task of email authentication using mongoengine User + django authenticate, here is how I'm working:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as do_login, logout as do_logout

def login(request):

    data = extractDataFromPost(request)
    email = data["email"]
    password = data["password"]

    try: 
        user = User.objects.get(username=email)
        if user.check_password(password):
            user.backend = 'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
            do_login(request, user)
            request.session.set_expiry(3600000) # 1 hour timeout
            return jsonResponse(serializeUser(user)) 
        else:
            result = {'error':True, 'message':'Invalid credentials'}
            return jsonResponse(result) 
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        result = {'error':True, 'message':'Invalid credentials'}
        return jsonResponse(result)
```